# Create a new user with permission to access app store

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to add a new account and allow that account to access the Bigcommerce App Store. 
I followed the tutorial on [Tutorial](https://storecoach.com/how-to-create-new-user-accounts)
I have created the account, assign all the permissions by setting the user role to Store administrator as shown below. Somehow, the user I have created still can't access Bigcommerce App Store.

Could someone please tell me what I am missing? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only store owners have access to the single click apps on the Bigcommerce Appstore at this point. This is both to install and access the app once installed. 
You can find documentation on that here: https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/How-do-I-access-and-install-the-new-single-click-apps-within-my-Bigcommerce-store-control-panel

------- UPDATE -------

As Alyss correctly indicates, BigCommerce has now updated the app system. Now, if an app is setup to handle multiple users, it is possible for users other than store owners to access an app.

Comment: As an addendum to this, it is now possible to allow non-store owner users to access apps if they support multiuser access.

Comment: @Alyss that is correct if the app has been configured appropriately. Thanks for updating.